# 'Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting the error 'The type or namespace 'MovementValue' could not be found - are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference' with the following code:

Would anybody be able to give me a helping hand as to what I am doing wrong (this is my first ever C# script)?

I would be so grateful!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;



public class playercontroller : MonoBehaviour
{

                private Rigidbody rb;
                private float movementX;
                private float movementY;

                void Start()
                {

                    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

                }


                void OnMove(InputValue movementValue)
                {

                    Vector2 movementValue = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
                    movementX = movementVector.X;
                    movementY = movementVector.Y;

                }

                void FixedUpdate()
                {

                    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movementX, 0.0f, movementY);
                    rb.AddForce(movement);

                }
}
```

Comment: Is it RigidBody or Rigidbody?

Comment: @Daniel the "d" is silent. No wait, that's another movie.

Comment: @DanielA.White after correcting, it still gives me an error for 'movementValue'!

Comment: You declared a parameter and variable with the same name

Comment: @Caledonian "an error"... please read [ask]. You're not supposed to keep asking new questions about the same piece of code. Read the error, research it, and if you have a new question, ask one containing all relevant details. Don't make us guess which error.

Comment: I think `Vector2 movementValue` should be `Vector2 movementVector`

Answer (score 1):

Check your cases in the class types:

You declare a `private Rigidbody rb;` which would be an instance of the type `Rigidbody`, but on this line - `rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();`, you're looking for components of type `RigidBody`.

The case is significant in C#, and as such, `RigidBody` (capital B) and `Rigidbody` (lower case b) are not the same.

On the Unity API reference, the class is named `Rigidbody` with a lower case b. Changing your code to match should resolve that error.

Comment: even after correcting that error I still get an error with MovementValue!